# How do you query by a field and return a dataset with Projex Orb?

Tags: activerecord

I am trying to find all the `reasons` objects with `type_id = 3`:

With ActiveRecord, I would expect the query to be:

```
reasons = Reason.where('type_id = 3')
```

then I could loop over each reason with:

```
reasons.each do |reason|
  # do stuff with the reason...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For simpler queries, you can use the new filter option which supports a shortened syntax:

```
reasons = Reason.all().filter(type_id=3)
for reason in reasons:
   # do stuff with reason
```

For more advanced queries, you can use the query syntax:

```
from orb import Query as Q
reasons = Reason.select(where=Q('type_id') == 3)
for reason in reasons:
   # do stuff with reason
```